# how to delete very large file on Linux

Tags: linux, join, split, unzip

I have a 63 GB file that needs deleting on Linux.  My trash is only 6 GB right now. I tried to split the 63 GB file into 63 1 GB files, and that worked.  However, the file I split remains, so I still cannot delete it.  I wanted to unzip this 63 GB file, but I found when I did that that it had a few places that were corrupt in it, so I have to delete it and try again.

Originally, I had 63 1GB files, .z01, .z02, .z03....,.z62,.zip.  I searched the internet, and found that the way to unzip this massive amount of files, was to first join them together, and that is the 63 GB file.  However, when I tried to unzip it, it only partially unzipped, and did not work, so I now need to delete this 63 GB file, and start again trying to join together the 63 zip files (.z01, .z02....,.z62,.zip) together in hopes that they are not partially corrupt this time, so that I may then unzip them to obtain my families memories.

A web site on which I had stored years of photos and videos is shutting down, and they sent me this zip files that must be joined together before they can be unzipped.

I did try the procedure on another 2 zip file total directory that this place sent me, so .z01,.zip (each 1 GB) were joined together in one 2 GB file.  I then unzipped these successfully without issue, and obtained some other upload from this site, and the 2 GB file deleted of course with no problem.  I used a program I downloaded from the internet to join them together (called HJ Split that both joins and splits files together).  However, I think I could have used the command line "join" to join the 2 zip files together too.  I used "unzip" to unzip the 2 joined files into my directories of photo and video memories on Linux.

Also - would it be possible to just increase the size of my trash temporarily to over 63 GB, so I can delete that corrupted file?  I had thought when I split that file, once that procedure completed it would delete the old huge file, but it's still there!  I can't get rid of it to start over.  The command I used was: split --bytes=1G joined_63GB_file.zip

Thank you - any help will help recover years of my family's memories, especially when my kids were very young.

Comment: drop down to console and rm it http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm

Comment: I was going to say, doesn't rm -rf ignore the trash altogether?

Comment: Thank you - I used rm -rf and it did remove the huge file without moving it to the trash.  I thought all files removed went to the trash.  I did know about -rf (recursive force) of file removals, but did not try it since I thought that huge file would go to my trash that was not large enough.  Thank you for answering kindly, since not everyone does! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

As the comments have mentioned, you can drop down into the terminal and just type `rm FileName` to skip the trash when deleting.

Alternately, if you are using a GUI file explorer, you can generally just use `Shift-Delete` to directly delete and skip the trash.

Comment: Thank you - see comment above - it worked without going to the trash (rm -rf largefile).

Comment: @user1943660 I do not think you need `-rf` to skip the trash.

Comment: I already deleted it so cannot test it, but perhaps then using the file gui (analogous to file explorer on windows) to delete on linux would move the file to the trash, but if you do it at the console, it never (even if you don't use the -rf qualifier) would move the large file to the trash - good to know - but will have to try another time when I have a file that big to delete!